# Nokogiri converting &nbsp; to ?. How can I get it to convert to a space

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I open my doc like this `doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(team_url))` and later on I'm parsing through an HTML tables `<td>` elements.

In the HTML, there is often an element that looks like this

```
<td>&nbsp;</td>
```

When I do a

```
content = row.xpath("td[1]/text()")
```

I end up getting `?` as a result for content, instead of a space.

Why is this, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Where do you see the `?`? In the console? `nbsp` is a non-breaking space, not a normal space, if the console is the wrong encoding it might not recognise the `nbsp` and diplay the `?` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Nokogiri converts "`&nbsp;`" to [no-break space unicode character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm).  You can do a global substitution to resolve.

```
content.text.gsub("\u00A0", ' ') # replace &nbsp; with space

content.text.gsub("\u00A0", '') # remove &nbsp;
```